# cq5. What filter I need use for upload my scaffold page?

Tags: aem, scaffold

I created a scaffolding page based on the info provided in this link
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/wcm/scaffolding.html

I currently have it within my instance only, but i want to package it and deploy to other instances.

What filter I need use to package my scaffold page?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where do you want to deploy this? If want to create a package and use it in some other instance, you can build the package using Package Manager(/crx/packmgr/index.jsp).

Comment: @rakhi4110 how to put scaffolding page to package?

Comment: Create a package in package manager. Edit the package and in the filters tab add filter that points to your scaffolding page (which would be residing under /etc/scaffolding). Click save and then build the package. Refer the [docs](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/package_manager.html). It is very straight forward.

Comment: /etc/scaffolding - what do I wanted

Comment: Am sorry. Couldn't get you.

Comment: @rakhi4110 I am novice in cq and I cannot to formulate question clearly, sorry

Comment: @ rakhi4110 I have rewarded it. Is this variant better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use filter that points to your scaffolding page.
You generally create scaffolding pages under `/etc/scaffolding`.

In case you are doubtful of the page's path, check the URL of your scaffolding page. You should be able to figure it out(see the highlighted part in the image below).

[image]

For more info on filters and creating package refer [Package Manager docs](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/package_manager.html).